# android retrofit get access token (Bad Request Error)

Tags: android, retrofit2, access-token

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyRpj.jpg)

this is my postman and access token.
How can I get access token with use retrofit
In postman Body parameters what equal in retrofit or Request.Builder ?
I got "Bad Request"

My ServiceGenerator:
(I use basic auth in retrofit)

```
public class ServiceGenerator {
public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:11050/";

private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());


public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String username, String password) {
    if (username != null && password != null) {
        String credentials = username + ":" + password;
        final String basic =
                "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();

                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", "Basic Og==")
                        .header("Accept", "application/json")
                        .method(original.method(), original.body());

                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
    }

    OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

My service Interface :

```
public interface LoginService {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/token")
Call<AccessToken> getAccessToken(
        @Field("grant_type") String grant_type);

}
```

> onCreate :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    init();


    loginService = ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class,"ss","ss");

    callAcc = loginService.getAccessToken("password");

    callAcc.enqueue(callAccCallBack);
    AccessToken accessToken;
    private Callback<AccessToken> callAccCallBack = new    Callback<AccessToken>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<AccessToken> call, Response<AccessToken> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            accessToken = response.body();
            edt_editText.setText(accessToken.getAccessToken());
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<AccessToken> call, Throwable t) {

    }
};
```

Comment: "I use basic auth in retrofit" -- but you don't use basic auth in postman.  Is your question on how to replicate the same kind of request you have in Postman? Or are you expecting basic auth to work?

Comment: on android, how to replicate the same kind of request I have in Postman? :)